# How to pass multiple shell arguments to be used as conditionals?

Tags: shell

I have a shell script divided like this:

```
# development
# do some stuff

# test
# do some stuff

# production
# do some stuff
```

I want to be able to choose which environment I want to deploy via args:

```
source deploy.sh prod # only deploy production
soruce deploy.sh development test # deploy development and test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `switch` construct in `bash` as follows, iterating over the arguments and performing your actions on each part.

```
for option in "$@" 
do
   case "$option" in
        "development")
            echo 'do development'
            ;;

        "test")
            echo 'do test'
            ;;

        "production")
            echo 'do production'
            ;;

        *)
            echo "Invalid choice made!"

    esac
done
```